# Calling Method while looping through an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

How can I call a method while looping through a list of objects and all its properties?

At the moment I am trying to do a setTimeout() in one of the properties of the object and then move on to the next property after the setTimeout() finishes the delay. I would also like to append an li to the DOM further down the array list while still printing the string in the statement.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is the javascript:

```
const lvls = {
 start: {
    lvlTitle: 'Lets Start!',
    delay: setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("On Lets Start click I am supposed to wait a few seconds and then proceed on to the next lvl..");
}, 1000)
  },
  lvl1: {
    lvlTitle: 'Drinks/Soda/water',
    statement1: 'lvl1 info...',
    statement2: 'lvl1 more info...',
    statement3: 'lvl1 more more info' && function createContent1() {
      var ul = document.querySelector('.text-container');
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('more text in this new div'));
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
   },
   lvl2: {
     lvlTitle: 'Portion Control/Meals',
     statement1: 'lvl2 info...',
     statement2: 'lvl2 more info...',
     statement3: 'lvl2 more more info' && function createContent2() {
       var ul = document.querySelector('.text-container');
       var li = document.createElement('li');
       li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('more text in this new div'));
       ul.appendChild(li);
     }
   }
 }

 function* deepValuesIterator(o) {
   if (typeof o === 'object') {
     for (const value of Object.values(o)) {
      yield* deepValuesIterator(value)
    }
    } else {
     yield o
    }
 }

 function* nextLevel(levels, generator, element) {
   while (true) {
     for (const value of generator(levels)) {
      yield element.textContent = value
     }
   }
 }

 const printText = document.querySelector('.text-container')
 const lvlsIterator = nextLevel(lvls, deepValuesIterator, printText)

 printText.addEventListener('click', () => lvlsIterator.next())

 lvlsIterator.next()
```

And Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="full-page">
 <div class="click-container">
  <ul class="text-container">
    <li class="text-content">
      <div></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Lastly here is a JSFiddle:
[Calling Method while Looping Through Array List](http://jsfiddle.net/mkgs079y/)

Answer (score 0):

Function have different type, so your code didn't call function.

I added checkout for function to your deepValuesIterator function.

```
function* deepValuesIterator(o) {
  console.log('')
  if (typeof o === 'object') {
    console.log('objects')
    console.log(o)
    for (const value of Object.values(o)) {
      yield* deepValuesIterator(value);
    }
  } else if(typeof o === 'function'){
    console.log('function');
    yield o();
  } else {
    console.log(' not       objects')
    console.log(typeof o )
    console.log(o)
    yield o;
  }
}
```

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendow/mkgs079y/22/)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I call a method while looping through a list of objects and all its properties?

Thats fairly simple, while iterating just check if the property is a function, if so call it.

> At the moment I am trying to do a setTimeout() in one of the properties of the object and then move on to the next property after the setTimeout() finishes the delay

There are some missconceptions here:

- The timeout starts when the script loads, not when the iterator reaches it, as its not a method but just a function call inside the properties expression.
- The timeout won't delay anything. There is no "blocking js", javascript solves such problems through callbacks, and that don't really work well with iterators natively (yet). But you could write a regular function that iterates over an iterator and passes a callback into every yielded function:

---

```
 function waitIterate(iterator) {
   var blocked = false;
   return function next() {
     if(blocked) return;
     const { value, done } = iterator.next();
     if(done) blocked = true;
     if(typeof value === "function") {
       blocked = true;
       value(() => (blocked = false, next()));
    } else { next(); }
  };
 }
```

So how can we use this? Like this:

```
 function* stuff() {
   alert("test");
   yield function(cb) { setTimeout(cb, 1000); }
   alert("test2");
 }

 printText.addEventListener('click', waitIterate(stuff()));
```

Your original code still needs some modifications, this is just to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I still have the issue of my function being displayed in the DOM. Any advice idea on why this is happening?